# Generate UI for mobile application

Tags: html, css, mobile, user-interface

I wanted to use any tool to design UI(by dragging necessary controls) for mobile application, which will give me the necessary HTML, CS (may be JS) code.

Please suggest me any **free** tool or browser plugin for this.

Thanks.

Comment: which type of development you prefer to do, i.e. mobile web site development or mobile application development?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the following links are best for you:

[jQuery UI](http://jquerymobile.com/)

[Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)

[Bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/)